# Bar Slider Display for Android

Tags: android

I am currently trying to make a custom display for an Android app.

My settings deals with range settings and the user's current speed. I am planning to display the settings and the current speed in the below format:

[image]

However, as of current I cannot see how to implement this kind of custom display in an XML. The widgets I currently have don't support this.

**In what way will I be able to implement this kind of custom display?**